# Does SSRS Report Builder Subreport Visibility Suppress Subreport or Hide It?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I want to know if when setting the visibility on as subreport to false, does the subreport still compile but is just hidden or does it suppress the report and keep it from running?  I'd like to have two versions of the same subreport and depending on variables in the main report, one of the two subreports would display.  But I don't want both compiling and running as that will cause some performance issues.

This is more of a question on how SSRS Report Builder operates.

Answer (score 0):

The last time investigated this was many years ago but as SSRS has not been developed much over the years I expect the same thing happens now.

The subreport is processed, at least the datasets are processed which can obviously lead to a lot of unnecessary processing time.

I had a situation where I wanted to display different charts in several scenarios. The way we built it was to pass the 'hidden' parameter to the subreport, which in turn passed the parameter to each of the subreport's datasets.

The dataset query would then look something like this.

```
IF @hidden = 0
    BEGIN 
        SELECT ColumA, ColumnB, AmountC FROM myTable WHERE Product = @Product
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ColumA = CAST(NULL as varchar(10)), ColumnB = CAST(NULL as varchar(10)), AmountC = CAST(NULL as Decimal(14,6))
    END
```

This way, the least amount of processing is done but the dataset always returns the same structure.